# jQuery dynamically drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

i'm having some trouble with drag and drop. if i put static field...it's works fine, but if i create dynamically, the draggable doesn't work.

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $( "#drag_item #data li").draggable({
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $( "#drag_item ol" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
            $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
        }
    }).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
        }
    });
});
```

Static html

```
<div id="drag_item">
    <ul id="data">
        <li>A</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Dinamically

```
function create_item() {
    for (var a = 0; a < data_array.length; a++) {
        $( "<li></li>" ).text('Data'+a).appendTo($('#data'));
    }
});
```

Any clue?

Comment: try to call ` $( "#drag_item #data li").draggable({
        helper: "clone"
    });` after `create_item` function complete

Answer (score -2):

You need apply .draggable every time the you have a changes in node. For example:

```
function create_item() {
    for (var a = 0; a < data_array.length; a++) {
        $( "<li></li>" ).text('Data'+a).appendTo($('#data'));
    }

    $("#data").draggable("destroy");
    $( "#drag_item #data li").draggable({
        helper: "clone"
    });
});
```